# Formulario Symfony no se envía

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con Symfony 5 y para los formularios utilizo la interfaz `FormBuilderInterface` que debería encargarse de los datos. El problema es que cuando actualizo un usuario, `$form->handleRequest($request)` no registra el envío del formulario.

Este es el archivo que se ocupa de crear el formulario, `UserType.php`:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TelType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [ 'label' => 'Nombre y apellido' ])
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, [ 'label' => 'Correo electrónico' ])
            ->add('password', TextType::class, [ 'label' => 'Contraseña' ])
            ->add('phone', TelType::class, [ 'label' => 'Celular' ])
            ->add('status', TextType::class, [ 'label' => 'Estado' ])
            ->add('category', ChoiceType::class, [ 'label' => 'Rubro' ])
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [ 'label' => 'Guardar' ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Y este es el controlador:

```php
<?php


namespace App\Controller;


use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\UserType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/usuarios", name="user_index")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->render('user/index.html.twig');
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/usuarios/crear", name="user_create", methods={"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function create(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $user = $form->getData();
            $user->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
            $user->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());

            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'El usuario ha sido creado correctamente');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('user_edit', [
                'id' => $user->getId()
            ]);
        }

        return $this->render('user/create.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/usuarios/{user}", name="user_edit", methods={"GET", "UPDATE"})
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, LoggerInterface $logger, User $user)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $logger->info('Formulario válido');

            $user = $form->getData();

            $user->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());

            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'El usuario ha sido actualizado correctamente');

            return $this->render('user/edit.html.twig', [
                'form' => $form->createView()
            ]);
        }

        $logger->info('Formulario inválido');
        dump($form);

        return $this->render('user/edit.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }

}
```

Por las dudas, esta es la vista; donde renderizo el formulario:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Editar usuario{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Editar usuario</h1>
    <div class="form">
        {{ form(form, { 'method': 'UPDATE' }) }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

La ruta `user_create` del controlador funciona bien. En el profiler de Symfony puedo ver que el formulario no se envió:

[image]

El formulario es devuelto y mostrado correctamente, salvo que hayan errores. Alguna idea de por qué no registra el envío del formulario?

#### Edición:

Esto es lo que muestra el Profiler:

[image]

Comment: Prueba poner en el method en vez de UPDATE, POST, así:  { 'method': 'POST' }

Answer (score 1):

Fíjate que el parametro que estás pasando en la url es el user id. Al crear el formulario le pasas como parametro la clase User pero todavía vacía. Lo que has de hacer es recuperar el usuario por ejemplo con un método find(user_id) antes de crear el formulario

Answer (score 1):

En el controlador cuando asignas el valor del form a la variable de `$user` sobrescribes el valor de la variable por el de la respuesta del formulario, esto no es correcto.

> $user = $form->getData();

Debes llamar directamente al atributo del objeto

```
....
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $logger->info('Formulario válido');

            $user->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());

            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();
```

Igual si el objetivo son estos campos de createAt y UpdateAt te recomiendo implementar [Doctrine Lifecycle Callbacks](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-lifecycle-callbacks)